# Selector does not work with mipmap image in android

Tags: android, android-selector

All I want is that an imagebutton which changes to another image when user press the button on. Following is my directory list. As you see I don't have drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi ..and others. And also I can't see mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi ..and others. My problem is I can't add selector xml for my imagebutton.
[directory list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ww5K.png)
Following image is my content_main file which known as activity_main.
[content_main.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX0nQ.png)
My program shows the image of button but when I add  android:background="@drawable/fbpressed" code piece in content_main, the program fails. it says unfortunately Login2 has stopped!

I tried lots of combination for my selector file which is fbpress.xml. like I tried android:icon="@mipmap/facebook_pressed" but it fails again and again. any idea?

Comment: Create drawable folder for hdpi, xhdpi etc inside res folder and put images in there and use `android:drawable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes guys I've solved the problem. I did not know that i should change my values/styles.xml file if i add an resource file into my button. (which is fbpress.xml)

Also I changed my folder representation from Android style to Project style so that i can see my mipmap-hdpi, mdpi etc.

[change from android to project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZu9w.png)
I add those lines into my styles.xml. fbpress is my resource file which is selector file.

```
<style name="fbpressed" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/fbpressed</item>
</style>
```

Following is my part of content_main.xml. I added  android:background="@drawable:fbpressed" and style="@style/fbpressed" lines into this file.
[imageButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYGA9.png)
And finally my button works =) Thanks for all your helps

Answer (score 1):

Please change you selector:

```
<selector>

    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/facebook_press" android:state_press="true">
    <item android:drawable= "@mipmap/fracebook">

</selector>
```

Please click the Android in you screenshot , and change it to Project.It can be more clear.